# Laravel 8: Google Authorization Error 400

Tags: php, laravel, google-authentication, laravel-socialite, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 to develop my project and I would like to use Google authentication system for my users to login.

So I downloaded package via `composer require laravel/socialite` command and added my information on `.env`:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=example
GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY=example
GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback
```

And then I defined them on `config/services.php`:

```
'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY'),
        'redirect' => 'GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL',
],
```

After that I created a controller on my `auth/` directory which is called `GoogleAuthController` and goes like this:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class GoogleAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }
}
```

And finally at my login blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('auth.google') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Login with Google</a>
```

But the problem with this is that it, whenever I test this, it says:

> **Error 400: invalid_request**
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL

So why am I receiving this error ? How to fix it ?

I really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Also if you want to take a look at my routes, here it is:

```
Route::get('/auth/google', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\GoogleAuthController::class, 'redirect'])->name('auth.google');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is wrong:

```php
'redirect' => 'GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL',
```

Should be

```php
'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL'),
```

And of course this redirect should point to Google, not your localhost.